# jQuery post to Campaign Monitor not working

Tags: jquery

I'm have been using this script to post Name and E-mail to Campaign Monitor. But it don't work anymore? I'm getting error at 'var jform'.
I'm getting ReferenceError: form is not defined:
var jform = jQuery(form);

```js
<script>
ajaxValidation = (function(){
 var _ajaxValidation = ajaxValidation;
 return function() {
  var originalResult = _ajaxValidation.apply(this, arguments);
  if(originalResult){
   var iframe_name = "crossdomainpost";
   if(jQuery("#" + iframe_name).length) return true;
   var jform = jQuery(form); // I'm getting error here!
   if(jQuery("input:checkbox[name*='Newsletter']", jform)[0].checked){
    crossDomainPost(iframe_name).done(function(){ jform.submit(); });
   }else{
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }
})();

function crossDomainPost(iframe_name){
 var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 var uniqueString = iframe_name;
 var r = jQuery.Deferred();
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
 iframe.style.display = "none";
 iframe.id = uniqueString;
 iframe.contentWindow.name = uniqueString;
 iframe.onload = function(){ r.resolve(); }

 var form = document.createElement("form");
 form.target = uniqueString;
 form.action = "http://mydomain.createsend.com/t/r/s/xxxxxxx/";
 form.method = "POST";

 // repeat for each parameter
 var input_name = document.createElement("input");
 input_name.type = "hidden";
 input_name.name = "cm-name";
 input_name.value = jQuery("#RSEProName").val();
 form.appendChild(input_name);
 var input_email = document.createElement("input");
 input_email.type = "hidden";
 input_email.name = "cm-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx";
 input_email.value = jQuery("#RSEProEmail").val();
 form.appendChild(input_email);

 document.body.appendChild(form);
 form.submit();
 
 return r;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's `var jform = jQuery(form);` supposed to do? Is it selecting the only form on the page (in which case it should probably be `var jform = jQuery("form");`)? Or is `form` supposed to be defined earlier in the code?

Comment: It's a signup form for an event. You can see full page here:
http://shop.kbhmadhus.dk/kurser/tilmeld/345-okoloft-danmark-konference-okologi-i-offentlige-kokkener